# MongoDB systemLog.logRotate doesn't work

Tags: configuration, mongodb

I was reading in the docs of Mongo for log file rotation but it doesn't work.

It's only writing every thing to one file and it doesn't split up in day files.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.logRotate

Here is my `MongoDB.conf`

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.4/bin/MongoDB.log
    logAppend: true
    logRotate: rename
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-local

storage:
    dbPath: C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.4/bin/data
journal:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: The `systemLog.logRotate` configuration value you've set determines the behaviour of the  [`logRotate` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/logRotate/#dbcmd.logRotate) when invoked, but you still need to set up a scheduled task (outside of MongoDB) to trigger log rotation. If you have already set up a scheduled task that isn't working, can you confirm the command line used to trigger log rotation? If you aren't sure how to set up a scheduled task, can you confirm your version of Windows?

Comment: Hmm.... So I still need to set up an external process like https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#Logging-Rotatingthelogfiles ?
I use it as a windows process in Windows 10.